# Loading UIView into another view that is smaller than screen size

Tags: objective-c

I am creating some kind of a pop up window .
I have a `UIView` that is smaller than screen size, and i want to load it with another view- that is created with `storyboard`(drag a `viewcontroller` to storyboard and give it a name).

What actually happens is that it works, but the view from `storyboard` is going out from the UIView bounds :

```
UIView *viewPopup = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)]; //pop up
UIViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"try"]; //from storyboard
[viewPopup addSubview:vc.view];
[self.view addSubview:viewPopup];
```

So here, the `vc` is starting at `50,50` but is going all the way out of the screen and not bound into the `viewPopup`. (which is `50+200` )
How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings for the viewcontroller size in the StoryBoard. Generaly a UIViewController from the storyboard takes up a whole screen so you will have to change some settings there to make it smaller.  You could also create it programatically or from a seperate nib if that is easier to modify.

[image: Set the size of the ViewController View]

[image: Try setting the viewcontroller size to freeform?]